# Working precision and pure functions in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

I have this function:

```
fun = (# - 5.0)^2.0 &
```

Then, I want to find the minimum:

```
 FindMinimum[fun[x], x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

It return:

```
 FindMinimum::precw: The precision of the argument function ((-5.+x)^2.) is less than WorkingPrecision (30.`). >>
{0, {x -> 5.00000000000000000000000000000}}
```

How can I get rid of the error? I do not want to use Integers in this function.
usage of `$MinPrecision = 30;` did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that the error arises because `5.0` is only precise to one decimal place...or rather to `$MachinePrecision`. You can try the following:

```
fun = SetPrecision[(# - 5.0)^2.0 &, 30];
FindMinimum[fun[x], x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

which returns (with no error):

```
{0, {x -> 5.00000000000000000000000000000}}
```

Indeed, try:

```
Precision[(# - 5.0)^2.0 &]
(* MachinePrecision *)

Precision[SetPrecision[(# - 5.0)^2.0 &, 30]]
(* 30. *)
```

My answer is based on this bit of the docs: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html

Here's a good tutorial on arbitrary precision in Mathematica: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html